# Php level and exp system

Tags: php

How can i make a level system where i have 2 table, one for the level and another for amount of exp earned?

I want to be able to manage the different exp requierments myself, like level 2 will need 340exp and level 3 need 450exp. I dont want to set one exp amount and then multiply it. I want to manage the whole system.

I also want to set default level and max level, and give exp directly to the database column without too much problem (for forum posts etc).

I have seen a few questions here but i find them outdated or just not what im looking for.

PS: sorry for bad english and bad explenation.

Comment: More of a http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ kind of inquiry

Answer (score 0):

I found a realy good solution and was able to rewrite it to work with my setup. if anyone is interested i will leave the original link and my edit of it bellow.

my edit:

```
<?php
// Connect to your database like you normally do, then get any value into the $count variable

$count = $exp;

if($level == 0){
  $lvl = 1;
}else{
  $lvl = $level;
}

if ($count >= 12800) { $lvl = 10; }
else if ($count >= 6400) { $lvl = 9; }
else if ($count >= 3200) { $lvl = 8; }
else if ($count >= 1600) { $lvl = 7; }
else if ($count >= 800) { $lvl = 6; }
else if ($count >= 400) { $lvl = 5; }
else if ($count >= 200) { $lvl = 4; }
else if ($count >= 100) { $lvl = 3; }
else if ($count >= 50) { $lvl = 2; }

// Render stars or any graphics/images according to dynamic $lvl number
$stars = "";
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $lvl) {
     $stars .= "&#9733;";
     $i++;
}
echo "level $lvl";
?>
```

Original link:
https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Experience-Level-Evaluation-Programming-Tutorial